# show percentage scale in ggMarginal plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

With this code:

```
ggMarginal(p1, margins = "x", size = 2, type = "histogram",
       col = "blue", fill = "orange")
```

I can make this type of plot:

[image: ggMarginal]

But I would like to show on the y axis of the histogram the values in percentage scale, could you help me?

Comment: Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Working on some data is much easier than throwing some guesses to answer your question.

Comment: https://github.com/ChrKoenig/R_marginal_plot

Answer (score 0):

you should import package `(scales)`, should look something like this

```
...
library('scales')
ggMarginal(p1, margins = "x", size = 2, type = "histogram",
       col = "blue", fill = "orange") + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

Comment: Thank you but it gave me this error: Error in ggMarginal(p1, margins = "x", size = 2, type = "histogram", col = "blue",  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator